# How does printf knows if variable passed signed or unsigned

Tags: c, printf, unsigned, signed

Given the following code snippet:

```c
signed   char x = 150;
unsigned char y = 150;
printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
```

The output is:

```
-106 150
```

However, I'm using the **same** format specifier, for variables that are represented in memory in the **same** way. How does printf knows whether it's signed or unsigned.

Memory representation in both cases is:

```
10010110
```

Comment: `150` is out of range for a `signed char` - so it overflows to a negative value (MSB is 1) of `-106`. This will be sign-extended when promoted to an `int`. The `unsigned char` type will be zero-extended, so keeps its original value.

Comment: There is a format control string, such as %d, %ld, %lld, %u, %ul.

Comment: You don't pass a `char` (signed or unsigned) to `printf()`. When dealing with `...` in arguments, they are subject to *default argument conversions*, ie, values of type `char` are converted to type `int`. That is the only type `printf()` sees in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does `printf` knows if variable passed signed or unsigned?

The `printf` function doesn't "know".

You effectively tell it by using either a signed conversion specifier (`d` or `i`) or an unsigned conversion specifier (`o`, `u`, `x` or `X`).

And if you print a signed integer as unsigned or vice versa, `printf` just does what you told it to do.

---

> I used the same specifier "%d", and it printed different values (the positive one and the negative one"

In your example, you are printing signed and unsigned `char` values.

```
signed   char x = 150;
```

The value in `x` is -106 (8 bits signed) because 150 is greater than the largest value for `char`.  (The `char` type's range is -128 to +127 with any hardware / C compiler that you are likely to encounter.)

```
unsigned char y = 150;
```

The value in `y` is 150 (8 bits unsigned) as expected.

At the call site.  The `char` value -108 is sign extended to a larger integer type.  The `unsigned char` value 150 is converted without sign extension.

By the time `printf` is called, the values that are have been passed to it have a different representation.

Comment: There is a typo: `-108` should have been `-106`.

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior if the wrong type is passed; from it, one cannot rely on “if you print a signed integer as unsigned or vice versa, `printf` just does what you told it to do.”

Answer (score 5):

`signed char x = 150;` incurs implementation defines behavior as `150` is not in the range of OP's `signed char`.

The 150 is an `int` and not fitting in the `signed char` range undergoes:

> the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. C17dr § 6.3.1.3 3

In this case, `x` took on the value of 150 - 256.

Good code would not assume this result of -106 and instead not assign to a `signed char` values outside it range.

Then ...

Commonly, both `signed char x` and `unsigned char y` are promoted to `int` before being passed as arguments to a  `...` function due to the *usual arithmetic conversions*.  (types in the range of `int` are promoted to `int`).

Thus `printf("%d %d\n", x, y);` is not a problem.  `printf()` receive 2 `int`s and that matches the `"%d"` specifiers.

Comment: Then, it received two **different** integers. Because it printed two **different** values. How that happened ?

Comment: @Youssef13 Answer amended.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first recognize this issue:

```
char x = 150;
```

`x` never had the value 150 to begin with.  That 150 is going to get auto casted to *signed char*.  Hence `x`, is immediately going to assume the value of -106, since 150 can't be represented within a signed 8-bit value.  You might as well have said:

```
char x = (signed char)150;  // same as -106, which is 0x96 in hex
```

Second, char and short values when passed as variable arguments get auto promoted int. as part of being put on the stack.  This includes getting sign-extended.

So when you invoke `printf("%d %d\n", x, y);`, the compiler will massage it to really be this:

```
 printf("%d %d\n", (int)x, (unsigned int)y);
```

the following gets put onto the stack:

```
"%d %d\n"
0xffffff96   (int)x
0x00000096   (unsigned int)y
```

When printf runs, it parses the formatting string on the stack (`%d %d\n`) and sees it needs to interpret the next two items on the stack as signed integers.  It references `0xffffff96` and `00000096` as value on the stack respectively and renders both to the console in decimal form.

Comment: You are correct - "pop" is the wrong term.  What I meant to say was "Access down the stack" or something equilanent.